# Coulombs law: calculate force exerted on one charge by the other two

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

[image: This a picture of the problem]

The drawing shows three point charges fixed in place. The charge at the coordinate origin has a value of q1 = +8.00 μC; the other two charges have identical magnitudes, but opposite signs: q2 = -5.00 μC and q3 = +5.00 μC.
(a) Determine the net force (magnitude and direction) exerted on q1 by the other two charges.

The answer states that the answer to part a is +0.166N directed along the y-axis.

How can the charge be in the y-axis?

I imagine that q2 and q3 pull on q1 with equal magnitude ( but opposite in direction) and cancel out each other's forces.

Does the x-component and y-component need to be considered in the problem?

I'm not sure how to solve. Can I get tips?

Comment: *"How can the charge be in the y-axis?"* Careful with all the new terminology you are learning. You probably mean *electric force* rather than *charge*.

Answer (score 1):

I think a diagram will help:

[image]

So at the end, the resultant force on q1 is just the y components of each force exerted by the q2 and q3 charges added together

Comment: why does the electron with a charge of q3 exert a force on the electron of q1? Shouldn't the electron with the greater charge exert the force on the other? Shouldn't the electron with a charge of q1 generate the force to repel the electron with a charge of q3?

Comment: what do the direction of your arrows represent? I ask as I don't understand why the bottom arrow points from the e- with a charge of q3 to the e- with a charge of q1.